# Mathematical expectation for learning theory

Tags: probability, measure-theory, reference-request, soft-question, machine-learning

Which advanced math topic is most relevant in fully understanding mathematical expectations and becoming comfortable with manipulating them?

To gain mastery in working with expectations over complicated math domain, fully understand what is random what is fixed, in continuous and discrete domains which advanced math course might be most helpful?

Comment: I think any standard course in meaure theory/stats should do.

Comment: Actually basic stats courses have not helped enough so far.  While contents around expectation seem clear in those topics in first look, once expectations are put in more complex context like what happens in learning theory, it becomes evident that the elementary understanding has not been enough.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at some introduction to Bayesian theory. The way expectation are treated there is more likely to exhibit the key properties you are looking for.